# How to assign variable more values

Tags: java

Is it possible to assign value to variable, which is equal to numbers in certain range? For example I want my variable x to have value of numbers in range 0-100.
To clarify, my code looks like this:

```
             if(name.equals("developer")&&action.equals("add "+X)){
                //Do something;
             }
```

I just want X to represent more than just one value.
Thank you :)

Comment: It's only possible by using a Container type like Array, List. Can you explain the usecase properly?

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a regular expression.

Comment: regex may also work. If he's looking for a certain range of numbers and not just a pattern though, it may be more difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
if(name.equals("developer")&&action.equals("add "+X)){  // X value resolves at runtime 
                //Do something;
             }
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he means

Comment: @wlyles edited as a generic type.It would be better,If OP responds :).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like X should be abstracted out into a class. If you want it to contain various values then these could be variables inside the class. For example a Human class might contain variable relating to height, age and waist size. That's three variables within X. Im not sure how this would work with the equals method in your example though as Im not sure what the `"add "` is for in it.

If you dont want a class but just dynamic collection of variables then use one of the Collection classes. Again you might have some problems with the equals by having the `add` in there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to validate the `action` string format. Then parse the `integer` and check that it's within the required range as follows

```
if (name.equals("developer") && action.matches("add\\s\\d{1,3}")) {
   // regex guarantees a successful parse now
   int num = Integer.parseInt(action.split(" ")[1]);
   // check the parsed int's range
   if (num >= 0 && num <= 100) {
    // Do something;
   }
}
```